# How to run animation on load CSS

Tags: javascript, css, animation, text, counter

How do I start counter on load? I was able to make it start on hover but never get it to work on load.

JS:

```
var root = document.querySelector(':root');
var rootStyles = getComputedStyle(root);
var start= rootStyles.getPropertyValue('--start');
var finish= rootStyles.getPropertyValue('--finish');
//function witch gives data for this values
root.style.setProperty('--start', +storedelo-300);
root.style.setProperty('--finish', +storedelo);
```

CSS:

```
:root {
    --start: 0;
    --finish: 0; 
  }
@property --num {
    syntax: "<integer>";
    initial-value: 0;
    inherits: false;
  }
  
 div {
   transition: --num 5s;
   --num: var(--start);
   counter-set: num var(--num);
 }
 div::after {
   content: counter(num);
 }
 div::hover {
   --num: var(--finish);
 }
```

And @keyframes is not working for some reson

```
@keyframes counter {
  from {
    --num: var(--start);
  }
  to {
    --num: var(--finish);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function to set the initial CSS variables values and then call it on window `DOMContentLoaded` [(MDN documentation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) or window `load` [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

```js
var root = document.querySelector(":root");
var rootStyles = getComputedStyle(root);
var start = rootStyles.getPropertyValue("--start");
var finish = rootStyles.getPropertyValue("--finish");
//function witch gives data for this values

function startCounter() {
  root.style.setProperty("--start", +storedelo - 300);
  root.style.setProperty("--finish", +storedelo);
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    startCounter();
});
```

Comment: I think, I'm doing something wrong. In my case with your answer "--start" and "--finish" sets to 0 and counter does not work

Comment: Do you have it online to check?

Comment: It's not online, I was trying to do some sort of OBS studio widget. I can send you a package if you want?

Comment: I also managed it to work. Not sure what the problem was. I just set up settimeout and change value of --start in it